# Updating Salesforce for Outlook for 15 computers at once?

Tags: salesforce-for-outlook

I work in an organisation as an IT Support. We rely heavily on Salesforce for Outlook.

All of our machines that currently use Salesforce for Outlook are using an outdated version of the software.

I want to update Salesforce for Outlook on all of our computers - is it possible for me to update Salesforce for all the computers at once? All the machines are part of a domain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is in this article: Salesforce for Outlook Silent Installation

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000171217

Using this technique you can do this on multiple computers

Comment: very nice! Have to save this for next time

Answer (score 0):

Salesforce is a web-based application - there is no concept of updating machines. What makes you think you are using an outdated version?

Comment: Sorry I do not know much about Salesforce. We use Salesforce for Outlook - so we install Salesforce on our machines which then syncs with Outlook.

Comment: Because on the Salesforce for Outlook side-panel it says 'Upgrade to Verson xxxxx"

Comment: I think the latest version for Salesforce for Outlook is 2.5.0. We are currently on 2.4